# Auto Update Price In OpenCart Product Page on Radio button Option Selection

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

I want to auto update price of products based on radio button selection

http://demo.wdsindia.com/yossi/index.php?route=product/product&path=18&product_id=59 here when I click on radio button of 14K, 18K but wrong price changed.

Like `14K option` price `add $50` in main price

and `18K option` price `add $100` in main price

but problem is when i select any option than it add $100 in main price.

> This is jQuery which I used to change the values

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.option').change(function() {
   var OriginalPrice = $('#thisIsOriginal').text();
   var OriginalCurrency = OriginalPrice.substring(0, 1);
   OriginalPrice = OriginalPrice.substring(1);

   var newPriceValue = $('.option :selected').text();
   var position1 = newPriceValue.indexOf("(");
   var position2 = newPriceValue.indexOf(")");
   position1 = position1+3;
   var finalPriceValue = newPriceValue.substring(position1, position2);
   if(newPriceValue.indexOf('.') == -1)
   {
    finalPriceValue = "0";
   }
   finalPriceValue = parseFloat(finalPriceValue) + parseFloat(OriginalPrice);
   finalPriceValue = finalPriceValue.toFixed(2);

   $('#priceUpdate').text(OriginalCurrency + finalPriceValue);
   });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post releveant html along with your code, ot a reference link to an external website. A demo in jsfiddle.net would help also

Comment: Instead of calculating this in JavaScript (due to a currency re-calculations) I would call a PHP script via AJAX that would calculate the price correctly - only send a `product_id` and a price to add (or maybe better also the actual product price for the case more options could be selected and the price would be extended in more iterations) and that PHP action should add/subtract the amount sent based on the currency (saved in the session)... Doing this thing whole in a JavaScript is an overkill!